# Session lock expired on reading deferred message from Azure Service Bus

Tags: .net, azureservicebus

I have 2 applications where application A is sending data sets of complex objects to application B. It is imperative that the objects are processed in a specific order foreach data set, which is why I am using a topic with sessions enabled on the Azure Service Bus, where each message has a session ID (representing a data set) and a sequence ID representing the order.

I am using a `ServiceBusSessionProcessor` to receive messages from the bus, it is initialized like this:

```
SessionOptions = new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions()
{
   MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
   AutoCompleteMessages = false,
   MaxConcurrentSessions = 4,
   ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock,
   SessionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
   MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession = 1,
};
SubscriptionSessionProcessor = SubscriptionClient.CreateSessionProcessor("TestTopic", "TestSubscription", SessionOptions);
```

When the message is received I check if the message is next in the sequence to be processed in if so I process the message otherwise I defer the message back on the bus

```
protected async Task HandleSessionMessageAsync<R>(SessionInformationBase sessionInformation, ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{
   var stateData = await sessionInformation.Message.GetSessionStateAsync();
   var sessionState = SessionStateManager.CreateSessionStateManager(stateData);

   if (sessionState.IsNextMessage(sessionInformation.SessionData.Sequence))
   {
      try
      {
         sessionInformation.ProcessorCall.Invoke();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         ExceptionTracer.TraceException(e);
      } 
      await sessionInformation.Message.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
      await HandleSessionStateAsync<R>(sessionInformation, sessionState); 
   }
   else
   {
      sessionState.DeferredMessages.Add(sessionInformation.SessionData.Sequence, message.SequenceNumber);
      //defer message directly on the message object (the message that was received on the ServiceBusSessionProcessor object
      await sessionInformation.Message.DeferMessageAsync(message);  
      await SetSessionStateAsync(sessionInformation.Message, sessionState.Serialize());
   }
}
```

When I process a message in sequence I check if the next message in line was already received and if so i try to read it from the bus like this:

```
if (!sessionState.NextMessageIsDeferred())
   return;
try
{
   var deferredMessage = await Receiver.ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync(sessionState.GetNextMessageSequenceId());
   ... //process deferred message
}
```

However when I call the `ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync` method I receive a Session lock expired exception. The session lock timeout is set to 5 minutes and I know that there were mere seconds between the deferral and reading the deferred message.

One potential issue is that I am using an object of the class `ServiceBusReceiver` to retrieve the deferred message, that is neither the original processor that received the message nor the object itself - but as far as I can tell those object are unable to retrieve deferred messages.

I tried deferring the message through the receiver object, replacing the processor object by the receiver object, but I always run into different dead ends.

I am using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.10.0 lib for this.

Any ideas what I am missing - why do my session lock expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So managed to figure this one out. According to the documentation, a deffered message can only be retrieved by the producer that deffered it in the first place. In my example that wasn't the case, but I refactored my code to use a `ServiceBusReceiver` to retrieve message from the bus, if the message was not the next in the sequence, the receiver deffered the message and the that same receiver was able to retrieve the deffered message again.